# Migrating email forwarding entries from DirectAdmin to Google App (Free edition)

Tags: email, mx-record, g-suite, mail-forwarding

I have a website hosted in a shared hosting account and it contains a DirectAdmin (DA) control panel. From there, I can see some email forwarding entries.

I would like to migrate the email server to the Google App's, I am going to change the MX records to point to Google email server in the DA. For the existing email accounts that I see in the DA, I will re-create them in the Google App.

But for those email forwarding entries, I am confused. If I keep them there, will they still work after I have changed the MX record pointing to the Google email server? If not, this means I will need to re-create them in the Google App, right?

Unfortunately, Google App (Free edition) does not seem to allow email forwarding like those in DA. Unless I choose to use other editons (http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=175745).

In DA, when I have created an email forwarding entry such as xyz@mydomain.com -> xyz@another-domain.com, I do not really need to create a dummy xyz@mydomain.com email account and DA will still do the forwarding properly.

The best I can do now, without upgrading the Google App edition, is to simply create dummy email accounts in the Google App and setup forwarding inside that email account, is this correct?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're moving the mail over the Google Apps, the MX record is going to point to Google Apps more than likely so the forwards on your DirectAdmin box aren't going to do a thing, so the dummy account method is probably your only option.

However, there's another gotcha to look out for! If you're going to keep the domain setup on the DirectAdmin box, you're going to need to disable the Local MX feature. DirectAdmin provide the instructions [here](http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=8). The reason for this is that if you don't, any time you try sending email to your domain from the DirectAdmin box, the Directadmin mail server will think it's local and refuse to pass it onto the Google Apps server.

If you don't have access to the "MX Records" page from your DirectAdmin login, you will need to contact your hosting provider.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. I have found a way without the need to create the dummy accounts but this only works if the email address to be forwarded to is in the same domain (http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33327).